# Expandable div panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make some expandable vertical div/panels. Here are some images, to make it more clear.

[image]

The red line represents where user should click and drag left or right, and after dragging left for example, right side should show more content, exactly like this:
[image]

Can somebody post some example for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) offers this feature. Check out [resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) on their website.

**EDIT:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/5thnwre5/) is a way to do this with jQuery UI's resizable. Note that the trick to get the other one to resize is not jQuery; I'm using pure CSS here:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
}
#content1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#content2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
}
```

And the HTML to go along with this:

```
<div id="content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div id="content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$("#content1").resizable({
    handles: "e"
});
```

To limit both of the `div`s' widths, you'd have to use a static minWidth and a dynamic maxWidth on the resizable element. In this case, since the `div`s match the window's size, the maxWidth would be the window width minus the minWidth value.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/5thnwre5/1/) is an example.

Comment: I know about it, but how to make it so when I expand one div other shrinks?

Comment: Nice. I tried using minWidth for resizable, but it only limits left div. Is it possible to limit both div?

Comment: You could simulate it by setting a maxWidth on the left div also. Posted a link to a new jsFiddle, check it out.

Comment: No problem! Keep in mind you'll need to reset it if the window resizes. :)